# Missing data for Table One: baseline characteristics and demographics

Tags: proportion, clinical-trials, observational-study

Many observational studies and clinical trials have what they often called a 'Table One'. This table compares the baseline characteristics/demographic variables of one or two study groups (i.e. treatment vs. control). Often times proportions are reported for categorical variables in addition to the actual counts. For example, if we only have one group, we can have something like:

N = 1000

Sex
Male 510 (51%)
Female 490 (49%)

Now suppose we have 3 missing values for male and 5 for female (total of 8). Sample size gets reduced to 992. The table will show:

Sex
Male 507 (?)
Female 495 (?)

I was wondering what the ? (the proportions) should be. Should it be 507/1000 or 507/992. Same goes for female.

In short, should missing values be included in the denominator for these proportions?

Thanks!

Comment: If the numerator counts only known (nonmissing) items, then so should the denominator.

Comment: @BruceET yes that's what I'm leaning towards. Do you perhaps have a reference to support it? It'd be very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Well, $507/1000$ is a lie, isn't it? Maybe reference should be "Thou shalt not bear false witness...."

Comment: Haha that's right! Thanks :)